# servlet package not found in my JDK 7 update 2

Tags: java, jsp

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

i have a source code containing the above imports and i run into a lot of error messages as the servlet package is not included in my installed JDK 7 update 2.

i am really confused and don't know why, Thank you a lot for any guide to fix my tiny issue.

**For future references: There is a file called servlet-api.jar in the tomcat\lib installed folder and you only need to add its path (including the filename+extension) in the CLASSPATH of the System->Advance...->Environment Variables list box. Then compile your java file with javac. It sure works then**

Comment: It comes with the web server may i ask which server you are currently using

Comment: Thanks i am using Apache Tomcat 7

Comment: check in the APACHE_HOME/lib is it containing the servlet-api.jar

Comment: Oh I see the jar file already but still don't know how to make it global for use now. Maybe some xml file i will need to fix somewhere in there to include the jar file right ?

Comment: If it is the server's lib folder than it is available for every web-app which is deployed on that server ..and if it is not available in /lib than you can download it from here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar and put it in lib folder.

Comment: Thanks, but that is strange, I am thinking I have to create a class file after compiling my java file then leave my class file in the class folder of the web-inf folder, before I can make any call to the code in the jsp application which will run in the tomcat server. Well Am I missing something ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use any IDE like eclipse.Add the server there build application and deploy it from IDE .IDE takes care of your classpath and everything.

Comment: Thanks, that is very good suggestion but by that way I will run into no problems to ask.

Answer (score 2):

servlet api doesn't come with standard JDK, You need to download it externally and add it in classpath

Comment: Thank you, I search oracle but i still couldn't find it any where there. May I ask for a link to download it please ?

Comment: It comes with the Servlet container that you probably need to download, too, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet api is not a part of standard JDK.